# FOR XML PATH : DISTINCT sort cost increased

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to put together only unique values in the concatenated string. My code is currently:

```
SELECT  PITEM2.orderid,
                    (SELECT  ISNULL(E.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + E.LASTNAME,' ') + ', ' AS [text()]
                     FROM F_PURCHASEITEM PITEM1
                     LEFT JOIN E__EMPLOYEE E ON e.EMPLOYEEID=PITEM1.APPROVED_BY
                     WHERE PITEM1.ORDERID = PITEM2.ORDERID
                       AND PITEM1.PISTATUS =
                         (SELECT POSTATUSID
                          FROM F_POSTATUS
                          WHERE POSTATUSNAME = 'Invoice Received') GROUP By ISNULL(E.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + E.LASTNAME,' ') + ', '
                       FOR XML PATH ('') ) [EmployeeNames]
                  FROM F_PURCHASEITEM PITEM2
                  WHERE ORDERID=305089 Group By PITEM2.orderid
```

This gives me the output I'd expect, but the cost of the query increased and execution plan shows the Distinct sort as 46.3%.

[image]

How can I decrease the cost for this distinct?

Comment: You can try ROW_NUMBER() and selecting only first occurence of record.

Comment: Can you implement SQL CLR aggregations? In editions where `STRING_AGG ` is not supported, you will get great optimizations using such.